# cPanel does not let me to set my Cron Job to run every minute

Tags: html, cron, cpanel

I am currently trying to run this script

`/opt/alt/php72/usr/bin/php -d memory_limit=-1 -d max_execution_time=0 /home/sboxgquk/public_html/forums/applications/core/interface/task/task.php fbe57fcf6e8f449336839593cc9f5297`

every minute in the Cron jobs section of cPanel. However the lowest amount of time between each job is 5 minutes. It will not let me go lower than 5 minutes.

A screenshot of my issue is [here](http://prntscr.com/ohgidd).

I have tried using `*****` for each interval and `*/1` for the minutes section, and expected it to let me run the job at `*/1` however it gives me the error `"You did not format the date and time settings correctly."` next to the minutes section.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using just a single star `*` in the minute field?

Answer (score 0):

You can select run every minute from the common settings. You can see that I'm able to do this. Screeenshot attached.[image]

Answer (score 0):

after checking the picture you provided, you are setting the wrong path of the cron use this path

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/username/public_html/yourfilename.php
```